# I am using react-router-dom V6 and facing wrong assets path in react build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

It looks bit more like a notes, but i am going to elaborate as much as possible.
In my react web app I am using react-router-dom v6 and this is my app.jsx code looks like

```
import { BrowserRouter, Link, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import { lazy, Suspense} from 'react';

const ScenarioPlanning = lazy(() => import("./pages/ScenarioPlanning"));
const SingleScenario = lazy(() => import("./pages/SingleScenario"));

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter basename='/'>
      <Suspense fallback={<div className='main-loader'><img src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/images/logo.png`} alt="Mavryck" /></div>}>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" exact element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="scenarioplanning" exact element={<ScenarioPlanning />} />
          <Route path="scenarioplanning/:id" exact element={<SingleScenario />} />
        </Routes>
      </Suspense>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}


export default App;
```

On localhost:3000 all the components renders fine but when I make react build to host it on server or even test it through serve package on my local system and when I try to access the  component then there appears the errors in the console are https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxbNe.png

`http://localhost:5000/scenarioplanning/static/js/251.400bc25d.chunk.js`

In my case assets are located in root so the path should be http://localhost:5000/static/... not http://localhost:5000/scenarioplanning/static/...

Comment: Seems the server should be configured to return the root index.html file for all page requests into the app. I believe it should work well with code-splitting, but I've admittedly not much experience in this scenario.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but that is already been handled by basename='/'.

Comment: Are you referring to the `basename` prop on the router? That only indicates what path the internal routes and links are relative to. It has no bearing on how the server serves the app. All routes and links are also relative from root `"/"` anyway by default, so passing `basename="/"` doesn't really do anything.

Answer (score 0):

you can add below code in you package.json file at the top,

`"proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:5000"`

Comment: It seems that you want me to add my local ip address corresponding to "proxy" property or I should it as it is "proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:5000". And can you please elaborate how this is going to help me? THANKS